# Fuse two arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have two NumPy arrays with unique elements of

when i do `np.unique(array_1)` i get `array([0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6], dtype=int8)`

when i do `np.unique(array_2)` i get `array([0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6], dtype=int8)`

What i want is to fuse these arrays, by which i mean if i do `np.unique()` i should get

`array([0, 2, 4, 10, 12]),dtype=int8)`

I tried `np.concatenate([array_1, array_2])`

but unique elements do not change ,i get

`[0 1 2 4 5 6]` as the unique elements.

Any suggestions on what i may try would be helpful, Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between your 2 arrays and your desired output? What exactly do you mean by "fuse"?

Comment: What do you mean relationship between 2 arrays?what specific information are you looking for?

Comment: Are you trying to add the two arrays element wise?

Comment: why does `0,1,2,4,5,6` and `0,1,2,4,5,6` lead to `0,2,4,10,12`?

Comment: I think your example is broken (neither I nor the other commenters understand what you're trying to do) but are you possibly looking for set-related functions like [`numpy.intersect1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html)?

Comment: @sacul i was hoping that by doing some operation on the array it would result in `0,2,4,10,12`, is there something fundamental im missing here?

Comment: i got [0 1 2 4 5 6 0 1 2 4 5 6] after concatenating as you described. could you please correct your code in question?

Comment: Hold on ,made a huge mistake while stating the problem,give me a second

Comment: `np.unique(array_1) + np.unique(array_2)` ?

Comment: can you show whole your original code so we can spot the problem?

Comment: Why could you get 10 and 12 from np.unique if they are not in the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sum up the arrays you can simply write:

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.array([0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6])
arr2 = np.array([0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6])
arr_result = arr1 + arr2
Output: array([ 0,  2,  4,  8, 10, 12])
```

If you had a different thing in mind, I am afraid that I don't understand

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'fuse'. Could you specify what the arrays look like before using `np.unique` on them? Otherwise it is unclear what operation will give the desired result.

Comment: Im confused myself here , give me some time to think ,ill be back in a while